# Выборка в excel

Tags: excel, выборка

Доброе времени суток, имеем таблицу такого типа (показывает сбои по устройствам)

[image: пример таблицы]

Задача такая: нужно сделать подсчет кол-ва сбоев по № каждого устройства и причиной сбоя.

Для подсчета кол-ва сбоев использовал формулу **=СЧЁТЕСЛИ($A$2:$A$10;A2)**
Но по этой формуле он будет выводить только общее кол-во повторений № из столбца **A**.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно сделать подсчет кол-ва сбоев c учетом столбца **B**. Чтобы это выглядело например так:

[image: желаемый результат]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь функцией `счётеслимн`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Excel-2003 и старше. Они, бедняги, о СЧЁТЕСЛИМН не слышали. Но и им можно помочь:

```
 =СУММПРОИЗВ(--($A$2:$A$8=$F2);--($B$2:$B$8=G$1))
```

Ссылки показаны для примера в заглавном сообщении.

Использование бинарного отрицания позволяет ускорить обработку по сравнению с записью

```
 =СУММПРОИЗВ(($A$2:$A$8=$F2)*($B$2:$B$8=G$1))
```

В отличие от подружек *СУММЕСЛИ, СЧЁТЕСЛИМН*, эта функция не умеет определять пользовательский диапазон, поэтому в ней нежелательно задавать ссылки на полные столбцы или строки.